# How do I stream large datasets in grails?

Tags: grails

Application requires a large download ( a recordset sourced from SQL server with ~200K rows or ~5MB) from a grails application.  In c# I would use a dataReader but gorm with a hasMany defaults to sets and list that must be populated before using them.

What is the grails way to handle larger datasets that should be streamed?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself, but I believe if you set the batchSize attribute for the relationship in the static mapping closure you can limit size of the collection to N results at a time.  Sorry it's not a complete answer, but it's definitely where I'd start looking if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Nope. Documentation is buggy too. :)  http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5470?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel